# Documents I should provide to confirm my home address?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

My question is about what documents should I provide to confirm/prove my home address?

I have not got a mortgage property or property deed because I do not own the place. Me and my husband just pay a rent every month can I provide a bank statement, or my personal phone bill, or health card?

Comment: Based on the tags, I'm *guessing* that you need advice on proving your address for a UK visa application. Is that correct?

Comment: @aleksia You can provide your rental agreement

Comment: anything else except from rental agreement? @Traveller

Comment: Do you pay separately for utilities like electricity or water?

Comment: @ChrisH THAT'S RIGHT!

Comment: @MichaelHampton UNFORTUNATELY NO! I ONLY PAY MY PERSONAL PHONE BILL

Comment: @aleksia Where in the application does it require you to prove your home address? AFAIK proof of legal residence may be supplied  https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk but that is not the same as requiring proof of address

Comment: In USA, you can go to USPS and make a "change of address" for a fee (not worries for the "old" address, put a random but known, address). In "New Address" put your current address (it's OK if you rent it). That works right as proof of residence (the document will be mailed to you in around one week).

Comment: @JuanCa I've never heard of such a thing.  It's clever, but probably unnecessary.  In my experience, the rental agreement and the personal phone bill would be sufficient, as would any piece of personally addressed mail, though my experience does not include applying for UK visas.

Comment: @phoog It have worked to me and some friends. (I know, OP is asking for UK and I live in USA). And yes, those documents work fine, but I think she does not have one of them (and usually they ask for two of them)

Comment: SO, IN THE CHECKLIST OF DOCUMENTS FOR THE APPOINTMENT THE REQUIRE A LETTER CONFIRMING THE HOME ADDRESS! I HAVE MY PERSONAL PHONE NUMBER BILL! MANY THANKS FOR YOUR HELP GUYS! MAYBE I WILL TRY TO FIND THE RENTAL AGREEMENT! @JuanCa

Comment: Don't you have to provide bank statements too, and don't they show your address?

Comment: @aleksia See my answer, a mobile phone bill is no accepted

Comment: @aleksia The checklist is NOT a list of mandatory documents. It is a list of possible documents you may want to include, as indicated at the top where it says ‘You can send in any document to support your application...’ and ‘Tick if you are including this document’ next to the generic list of common documents (source: I am looking at the checklist from my partner’s last application in 2018). If you have a rental agreement, you should find it and include it, since it would help you demonstrate ties to your home country.

Comment: @aleksia which country are you applying in?  I am a bit confused about "documents or the appointment."  Can you [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/148104/edit) the question to include a link to the list that you are asking about?

Comment: @phoog AFAIK the checklist the OP is referring to is generated as part of the online application process. I’m not aware of it being published separately eg on gov.uk I think this type of question has been asked before on TSE but I can’t find an example / dupe at the moment